# Device found by LightBlue but not iOS CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm using a BLE Shield on an Arduino - LightBlue detects correctly the BLE shield. Now, I'm trying to make an app that scans for all the BLE devices and connect to the right one so I can send some information to my shield from my app.

But the app doesn't detect the BLE Shield (it detects another BLE device though...).

My code is the following:

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{

    switch (central.state) {
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
            msg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use."];
            [cbcManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180A"]] options:nil];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:   (CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
    NSLog(@"%@\n--------------------", advertisementData.description);
}
```

I checked with LightBlue, 180A is the right service UUID for my shield. I also tried to scan by passing a nil value instead of the service UUID but it still can't be detected.

The code seems to work as one of my BLE device is found...Any ideas why my shield can be detected by LightBlue and not this piece of code?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you included. And if you can discover other devices when passing nil for the services array, then you know everything is hooked up correctly core Bluetooth wise. So that leaves your Bluetooth shield or your testing device as the culprit.

Comment: You could try passing the allow duplicates option when scanning (I can't remember the constant off he top of my head and I can't look it up right now, check the docs) but all that should do is spam the logs with discovery messages.

Comment: Thanks Santa Claus, allowing duplicates solved my issue!

Comment: Interesting! I'll post it as answer, although I'm surprised that worked. Glad to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try passing the allow duplicates option when scanning, since it's possible its discovery is being suppressed if it thinks it's a duplicate.

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];    

[cbcManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
```